# How to add position in topright and abolute in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
var command0 = L.control({position: 'topright'});

command0.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div0 = L.DomUtil.create('div0', 'command0');

    div0.innerHTML = '<form><input id="command0" type="checkbox"/>1. Layer Adı</form>'; 
    return div0;
};
command0.addTo(map);
```

This code works but when I add position:'absolute', 'topright',
it doesn't work.
I need to align many of checkboxes. Please help.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot at least to show what's wrong? A jsFiddle would be useful as well.

Comment: I don't know how to add parameters of position if I have a tow Properties

Comment: {position:'absolute', 'topright'}
doesn't work

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with the map and your control: http://jsfiddle.net/e04cwb9s/ . Uncomment line 16 to set `position: absolute` to the `div`. It is not clear to me why you want to do that though. Maybe you want to set an absolute position to the `form` rather than the `div`?

Comment: I want to add a set of checkboxes on map 
in the topright but checkboxes does align on straight column
so I need to coordinate its

Comment: Then wrap each input tag within a div and you're done: http://jsfiddle.net/e04cwb9s/1/ . Alternatively you can play with CSS as well.

Comment: but if  name of one of them toller than the another one will n't align

Comment: I will take a snapshot

Comment: How to add photo here ?

Comment: There is a little "image" button with a twin peak mountain and sun (or moon?) that you can click on when you are editing your question.